# ElasticSearch: ignore_malformed not working

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I tried to put `ignore_malformed` for the property of a field in ElasticSearch Mapping.

```
EClient.indices.putMapping(
  {
    index: 'activities',
    type: 'user',
    body: {
      properties: {
        meta: {
          type: 'object',
          ignore_malformed: true, // meta is dynamic
        },
      },
    },
  },
  (err, res) => {
    console.info('Put Mapping Error:', err);
    console.info('Put Mapping Res:', res);
  }
);
```

But I get

```
response: '{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Mapping definition for [meta] has unsupported parameters:  [ignore_malformed : true]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Mapping definition for [meta] has unsupported parameters:  [ignore_malformed : true]"},"status":400}'
```

According to the documentation: [ignore_malformed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-malformed.html#ignore-malformed) it should work.
Is there someone who can tell me what is wrong with my codes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation written isn't accurate as discussed [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/12366). I tried experimenting with ignore_malformed parameter and found that it doesn't work with strings and object type, though it works with **integer** as expected. You can probably raise a ticket for elasticsearch or use the workaround discussed in this [link](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/12366).

Answer (score 5):

try `enabled: false` instead of `ignore_malformed` for objects. This makes sure that this field can have an arbitrary inner structure (however it is not searchable then)

Comment: exactly. This is one of the workarounds discussed in the link posted in my answer.